# Command to get adapter type

Tags: aix, adapter

Do you know if there is a command for AIX servers to check which is their adapter type? I am trying to find if my AIX server is NPIV or vSCSI

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsdev -C -H -S a -F 'name class subclass type'`

the subclass column should display fcp or vscsi